# Why is the homepage on JonathansCorner.com displaying oddly on mobile Safari?

Tags: css, cross-browser, iphone, mobile-safari

On my website at http://JonathansCorner.com/, the site as a whole displays well in mobile Safari, and the homepage displays well on (desktop) Firefox, Opera, Safari, and IE, but the homepage specifically does not look at all good on mobile Safari:
it
displays
one
word
per
line,
stretching
out
the
text
vertically.

I've tried several things to see if I can alter the behavior, and nothing I've tried seems to budge it. Moving the slideshow to an iframe, commenting it out, correcting HTML errors, commenting out the mobile stylesheet, nada. Every other page I've tried within the site looks as intended in mobile Safari, and I have not been able to duplicate the issue in any desktop browser.

Comments on how I can get the homepage to look reasonable in mobile Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the site using regular Safari, and then attempt to minimize the window, you'll see that the same thing happens.

Setting the [minimum width property](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_dim_min-width.asp) may help.

Comment: Setting the minimum-width property helped indeed; it now looks as intended on my iPhone. Thanks!

(I'd still like to know how to address the problem instead of mitigating the symptom; anyone else?)